# Unable to create a very specific user with host other than %

Tags: mysql

I have a very strange issue, which i'm not sure even how to debug
I have two users: `user1, user2`

Created `user1` just fine with ansible playbook (`mysql_user`), trying to create the 2nd user - fails.

Logged inside the server's `mysql>` and tried to create it mysql - wasn't able.
The only way for me to create the user was with `host=%` but I don't want to because the fact that there's something wrong here - causing the playbook to fail all the time on this specific user.

```
# Verified no user exists
mysql> select user, host from mysql.user;
...

# to be on safe side
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

# 127.0.0.1
mysql> CREATE USER 'user2'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY '123';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'user2'@'127.0.0.1'

# localhost
mysql> CREATE USER 'user2'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'user2'@'localhost'

# %
mysql> CREATE USER 'user2'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '123';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)


mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version';
+---------------+--------+
| Variable_name | Value  |
+---------------+--------+
| version       | 8.0.26 |
+---------------+--------+
```

Any ideas ? queries to check ?
Appreciate in advance

Comment: Sorry, always happens to me, i can spend a week on an issue and the minute i write a post about - i find the solution somehow. the issue is - the user isn't listed in `mysql.user` - but for some reason it is found under `mysql.db` with (`localhost` and `127.0.0.1`) this is why i couldn't use those hosts - but could use any other

Comment: `%` does not include `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually was able to find the issue. The user didn't really exists in `mysql.user` but existed in `mysql.db`

`mysql> select Host,Db,User from mysql.db where User='user2';`

| Host | Db | User |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 127.0.0.1 | mytable | user2 |
| localhost | mytable | user2 |

This ^^ prevented me from creating the user with these hosts ... but any other host - was actually fine ( even `%` )
Removing these entries solved my issue ...